# Fill in FDF file with PHP

Tags: php, pdftk, fdf

I have created a FDF with PDFtk, however I cannot find any documentation online on how to fill out the FDF file with PHP. `fdf_set_value` is throwing a "function undefined" error. I'd like to fill out the FDF without having to parse through the /V() lines if possible.

Code:

```
fdf_set_value("~/Desktop/my.fdf", "field_1", "value_1");
```

Comment: The [`FDF extension`](http://php.net/manual/en/fdf.installation.php) is unmaintained and considered dead.  That said, 'function undefined' means you need to install the FDF PECL extension.